# Android studio - byte operations - changing value

Tags: java, android, byte, operations

I have a problem with bit operations

```
int progress = slider.getProgress(); value of user input
```

then I have to do shift left and change it to HEX

```
int shl = 1<<progress-1;
String hexStr = Integer.toHexString(shl);
```

Nex Im sending bytes by BT

```
byte bit = Byte.decode(hexStr)
command[2]=bit;
```

Now the problem
If user set for example 2 it is ok 0b100 = 0x04

But if user set 5 0b10000 = hexStr = 10 in command[2] it gets value 0x0A

Why is it changing value?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with bit shifting, but are you sure you are actually experiencing an error? If I still remember how  to do this, then 5 is 0101 in binary, which becomes 1010 when bit-shifted left. 10 represented in Hex is A, which is the value you are getting.

Comment: I need only one "1" in whole command to send by BT
If user set 5 it means 5th led should light so 10000 
If user set 10 - 10th led should light 1000000000 
Im not translating decimal to bin or hex, but the user input tells on which position "1" should go
Hope its clear :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"But if user set 5 0b10000 = hexStr = 10 in command[2] it gets value = `0x0A`. 
>
>   **Why is it changing value**?"*

It is **correct**. What different result are you expecting?

For example :  If `progress` is **5** then...

- Doing bit shift like `1 << progress-1` == `1 << 4` = (resulting bits= `0001` `0000`) which gives : 
  `int shl = 10` **in hex** format or even `int shl = 16` **in decimal** format
- Doing `String hexStr = Integer.toHexString(shl);` puts `shl`'s "10" hex string value to the other string `hexStr` (*ie:* is also now a "10")...
- Doing `byte bit = Byte.decode(hexStr)` makes a byte with a **decimal** value of `hexStr`'s "10".

This is how your result is `command[2]` saying **hex** value of `0x0A` which == **decimal** value of `10`.

....

> *"I'm not translating decimal to binary or hex, but the user input which tells on which position "1" should go. Hope it's clear..."*

Why not just write "1" and then add as many zeroes as required (*padding*)?

Note: I'm not sure what value `command[2]=` is supposed to get. Maybe it checks the 8 bits of that byte, or maybe it expects a number (integer). It's confusng becuase your numbers rely on *"1 followed by zeroes"*, also binary can be *"1 followed by zeroes"*

- Binary : There are 8 bits in a byte, so the max binary you can send is `10000000` only.
- Integer : A single byte is **signed** so the max value s 128. By this logic your options are `1`, `10`, `100` only.

See if this helps (check which `command[2]=` you want. I've commented `//` them out for now) :

```
    int progress = 5; 
    int shl = 1 << progress-1; //why??

    String hexStr = Integer.toHexString(shl);
    String shlStr = Integer.toString(shl);

    String zeroStr = "";

    byte bit = Byte.decode(hexStr);
    //command[2]=bit;

    System.out.println("shl result string  : "  + shlStr);
    System.out.println("Bytes string hex : "  + hexStr);

    //# Padding
    for(int i = 0; i < (progress-1); i++) 
    { zeroStr += "0"; }    

    shlStr = "1" + zeroStr;
    //command[2]= Byte.decode(shlStr);

    System.out.println("Result string hex : "  + zeroStr);
    System.out.println("shi padding string  : "  + shiStr);
```